# How to change Chapter 1 to 1. Chapter I

Tags: numbering, chapters

Is there any way to change that? All I managed to do is Chapter I 1.
how can I change it to 1. Chapter I ??

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter \Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you want this `Chapter I` to appear? In the chapter heading? In the ToC, in the page headers?

Comment: Why you like to have Arabic and Roman chapter numbers at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view it is never a good idea to change the `\the...` counter format macros too much.

Rather 'inject' some code into the chapter header command `\@makechapterhead` with `\xpatchcmd`, having a `\chaptertitleformat` hook which can be defined at will.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newif\ifusestrangechapter
%\usestrangechapterfalse % Toggle the % 
\usestrangechaptertrue

\makeatletter


\ifusestrangechapter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
}{
  \huge\bfseries \chaptertitleformat%
}{\typeout{Success}}{}
\fi
\makeatother


\newcommand{\chaptertitleformat}{%
  \thechapter.\ \chaptername\space \Roman{chapter}%
}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}

\chapter{Foobar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Madd3: You're welcome! Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to repeat the chapter number but here is how it works:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\arabic{chapter}. Chapter \Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
```

Comment: This will add an empty chapter number in the ToC ...